# How to redirect to the login page if the path is null using the modules in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ui-router, angular-routing, angular-router

I have an angular application, and created the login and dashboard pages and  my requirement is while redirecting it has to go to login page and it has to go to dashboard page only when the path is dashboard.

I have created the user-pages folder for login and created the module within the user-pages folder.

**app-routing.module.ts**

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/user-pages/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'user-pages', loadChildren: () => import('./user-pages/user-pages.module').then(m => m.UserPagesModule) },
```

**user-pages.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { RegisterComponent } from './register/register.component';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
]
@NgModule({
  declarations: [LoginComponent, RegisterComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild(routes)
  ]
})
export class UserPagesModule { }
```

I want to show the login page only when executing.

Can anyone help me regarding this

Comment: A solution might be to set another route for that path you're redirecting to. For example { path: 'user-pages/login', component: LoginComponent }

Comment: Thanks@fonzane ,but I am unable to understand can you please edit the above code

Comment: You need to share the user-pages routes too .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove empty path redirection

```
const routes: Routes = [

  { path: 'dashboard', component: DashboardComponent },
  { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },
  { path: 'notifications', component: NotificationsComponent },
  { path: 'user-pages', loadChildren: () => import('./user-pages/user-pages.module').then(m => m.UserPagesModule) }
];
```

and change user-page module routing like following

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: LoginComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
]
```

And add the routing in app components ngOnInit

```
ngOnInit(){
   this.router.navigate(['/user-pages']);
}
```